# Is this the correct behavior of ast parsing

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on learning how to use and how golang's ast library works. I am parsing https://github.com/modern-go/concurrent, avoiding the test files and the go_below_19.go since it causes errors.

My problem is with the parsing of these lines in the file `unbounded_executor.go`,

```
var HandlePanic = func(recovered interface{}, funcName string) {
    ErrorLogger.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s panic: %v", funcName, recovered))
    ErrorLogger.Println(string(debug.Stack()))
}
```

The ast.Ident for `ErrorLogger` in both instances have a nil obj.

But, I believe that it should not be nil and should reference these lines from `log.go`,

```
// ErrorLogger is used to print out error, can be set to writer other than stderr
var ErrorLogger = log.New(os.Stderr, "", 0)
```

Am I wrong, or is there a problem with the parser? I've followed several references on parsing files and reuse a *token.FileSet across each of the files and use ParseComments as the mode.

edit:

There is a large code base surrounding this, so the code demonstrating this will include snippets.

This is performed with the same fset across all non-test go files, without build restrictions that would stop the code from being used with 1.16

```
parsedFile, parseErr := parser.ParseFile(fset, filePath, nil, parser.ParseComments)
```

Comment: You should also include your ast code and demonstrate how you came to this problem.

Comment: Call [NewPackage](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#NewPackage) to resolve ids.

Comment: [Type checking](https://github.com/golang/example/blob/master/gotypes/README.md#identifier-resolution) the ast might help.

Comment: @CeriseLimón This was it! As per the docs `It resolves unresolved identifiers across files and updates each file's Unresolved list accordingly`.For anyone wondering the code I used was `ast.NewPackage(fset, parsableFiles, nil, nil)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [ast.NewPackage](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#NewPackage) to resolve identifiers in the AST:

```
fset := token.NewFileSet()
files := make(map[string]*ast.File)
for _, name := range []string{"unbounded_executor.go", "log.go"} {
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, name, nil, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    files[name] = f
}

ast.NewPackage(fset, files, nil, nil)

ast.Inspect(files["unbounded_executor.go"], func(n ast.Node) bool {
    if n, ok := n.(*ast.Ident); ok && n.Name == "ErrorLogger" {
        fmt.Println(n.Obj)
    }
    return true
})
```

Because a proper importer is not provided and the list of files does not include all files in the package, NewPackage returns unresolved symbol errors.